# Packages Disappear After Sublime Text 3 Update

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, package-control

I just updated to Build 3114 and now all my packages have disappeared. I reinstalled Package Control, but when I go to Sublime Text > Preferences > Browse Packages, all I see is Package Control-related files. Is there a way I can restore them? Even a list of them would be fine.

Comment: Which specific packages have disappeared? Plugins installed by Package Control? Those are the only folders that should be in the `Packages` folder - all of the default packages that ship with Sublime are in `.sublime-package` archives stored elsewhere. This is a change from Sublime Text 2. Did you just upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Check ignored packages in your settings. Sublime likes to ignore incompatible packages.

Comment: I resolved this issue a while ago, but your comment helped me figure out a new issue I'm having, with ST3 not recognizing Package Control. I went into my settings and found a few packages that were ignored, including Package Control. Thanks!